# How to save the output from rxNeuralNet (an mlModel) for reuse?

Tags: microsoft-r

I used rxNeuralNet and got a great result.  I'd like to save it for future use.

```
nnOutput <- rxNeuralNet(formula = savedFormula, data = inputData, 
                        type = "regression", acceleration = "sse")
```

I can use the nnOutput with rxPredict, and validate my answers.

```
rxPredict(nnOutput, data = testSet, outData = tempXDF)
```

Now I want to save the output, so I can reuse it later.  (Training time wasn't insignificant.)  I can't seem to find any examples on doing so.  I've tried:

```
rxDataStep(inData = nnOutput, outFile = tempXDF, overwrite = TRUE)
rxImport(inData = nnOutput, outFile = tempXDF, overwrite = TRUE)
write.csv(nnOutput, file = "c:\\temp\\temp.csv")
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have SQL Server, you can persist the mode as binary to SQL, by using [`rxSerializeModel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/r-server/r-reference/revoscaler/rxserializemodel) and/or [`rxWriteObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/r-server/r-reference/revoscaler/rxwriteobject).

You can also use the "bog-standard" R `serialize` function, or `save`, or `saveRDS`.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A `rxNeuralNet` model object is just a regular R object. You can use the usual R methods for handling it.

For example, assuming your data is a data frame:

```
glmMod <- glm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data=dat)
nnMod <- rxNeuralNet(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data=dat,
                     type="regression", accel="sse")
save(glmMod, nnMod, file="models.rdata")
```

---

The next time you start R:

```
load("models.rdata")
glmPred <- predict(glmMod, newdat)
nnPred <- rxPredict(nnMod, newdat, outData=NULL)
```

Comment: Also a good approach. Saving on SQL seems like a better fit for my particular use case, but this good too!

Comment: If an answer is helpful, you should upvote and/or accept it.

Comment: I tried to upvote, but I don't have enough points yet apparently.